# What is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \bar{z}\,\partial z}\log|z|^2$?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Consider the function
$$\Bbb C-\{0\}\to\Bbb R,\quad z\mapsto\log|z|^2.$$
What is
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \bar{z}\,\partial z}\log|z|^2?$$

**Try:** I am no sure if the second step is justified, but this is what I got:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \bar{z}\,\partial z}\log|z|^2=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \bar{z}\,\partial z}\log z\bar{z}=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \bar{z}\,\partial z}\left(\log z+\log\bar{z}\right)=0+0=0.$$
Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is zero. You can always go back to the real-version:
$$f:\Bbb R^2-\{0\}\to \Bbb R,\quad f(x,y)=\log(x^2+y^2),$$
and use
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right),\quad\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right).$$
Also, since $f$ is continuously differentiable, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ commute and we find
$$\frac{\partial }{\partial z}\frac{\partial }{\partial \bar{z}}f=\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}\right)f.$$
The rest is is straightforward calculation.